# Copying data between two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy data from a closed workbook to another closed workbook but I keep getting `Runtime error 9, subscript out of range`. Both files are placed on my desktop under the same path. I am trying this example from a book I am learning from:

```
Sub CopyRange3()
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Set Rng1 = Workbooks(“File1.xlsx”).Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“A1”)
    Set Rng2 = Workbooks(“File2.xlsx”).Sheets(“Sheet2”).Range(“A1”)
    Rng1.Copy Rng2
End Sub
```

Can someone explain what is going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workbooks is a collection of the currently open workbooks. To use this you'll need to open them both.

You can turn off screen-updating, open them both, copy the data, close them both, saving the second book.

---

You get the error message "Subscript out of range" because "File1.xslx" is not a member of Workbooks, because it isn't open.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I'll give that a try. Still a noobie at vba so gonna have to google some parts. Ill accept the answer as soon as this thing lets me (y)